# how to make get request with Authorization api key value in header Swift

Tags: swift, get, authorization

[image]

below is my get request code. but getting 403 error ...please help!

```
    func getUser(completion: @escaping(Result<User?, AuthenticationError>)-> Void) {
    let loginVM = LoginViewModel()
    let token = loginVM.accessToken

    guard let url = URL(string: myURL) else {
        completion(.failure(.custom(errorMessage: "URL is not correct")))
        return
    }
    var request = URLRequest(url:url)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.setValue("Bearer \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            completion(.failure(.custom(errorMessage: "No data")))
            return
        }
        guard let registerResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: data) else{
            completion(.failure(.custom(errorMessage: "no response")))
            return
        }
        completion(.success(User))
        
    }.resume()
    
    
}
```

and instruction from my backend guy for this part is this :
[image]

I tested on Postman It work as like charm. It must be happen in my request code with Authorization....

Comment: This is Swift -- nothing about this is specific to SwiftUI, which is a UI framework.

Comment: @jnpdx just fixed my question title to Swift. Do you see any problem with my get request? Do you know why I am getting 403 error? what I can think is I am sending the token in wrong way maybe. I am fairly new .. anyway please help!

Comment: @moniqueyj is the "Bearer" value required in the "request.setValue" method? Have you tried sending directly the token? Like this: request.setValue(token, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

Comment: @Nahuel Roldan yes I did. It wasn't working...throw 403 error.

Comment: the response from server --> { Status Code: 403, Headers {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" =     (
        "x-access-token, Origin, Content-Type, Accept"
    );
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" =     (
        "http://localhost:8081"
    );
    Connection =     (
        "keep-alive"
    );
    "Content-Length" =     (
        30
    );
    "Content-Type" =     (
        "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    );
    ....}).

Comment: Ohh, ok. How about this? request.setValue("x-access-token: \\(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

Comment: @NahuelRoldan tried just now . no luck yet.. same error message..

Comment: Mmm maybe you can try this approach: after setting the header, print the request as cURL, and then import it in Postman. Then you can compare the imported request with the request you already have working in Postman. This gist can help you to get the cURL from the URLRequest: https://gist.github.com/abhi21git/3dc611aab9e1cf5e5343ba4b58573596